# MySQL Query Problem with INTERVAL, need 0 if no data provided

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, intervals

i have the following statement:

```
SELECT
count(rs.rsc_id) as counter
FROM shots as rs
where rsc_rs_id = 345354
AND YEAR(rs.timestamp) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(rs.timestamp,'%Y%m')
```

rs.timestamp is a unix timestamp

Output would be like for each row / month a numeric like '28'

It Works fine, but if i have inconsistent data, like only for the past three month (not for all six month), i get no return from my Database. I would like to have every time there is not data for this month, 0 returned...

any suggestion? 
i thought about some case statements, but this seems not so good...

thanks!!

Comment: The way you've written this query, you are taking the current date (2011 Mar 18), subtracting six months (2010 Sep 18), and then taking the year from that date (2010).  You then search for all records with that year.  This disregards the first 3 months of this year as well as considers thing as much as 15 months old right now (Jan 2010).  Do you, instead, mean to do `AND rs.timestamp > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)`?

Comment: ahh you are right, thanks!!

but is there a way to fill the remaining months with no data with a simple 0 ? so that i always get a return of 6 rows?

Comment: if rs.timestamp is a unix timestamp => year(rs.timestamp) IS NULL

Comment: yes thanks, no i did just a case when counter is NULL then 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only 6 months, a date table seems unnecessary, although this looks complicated (it really isn't!)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(N.PivotDate,'%Y%m'), count(rs.rsc_id) as counter
FROM (
   select ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL N MONTH) PivotDate
   FROM (
       select 0 N union all
       select 1 union all
       select 2 union all
       select 3 union all
       select 4 union all
       select 5 union all
       select 6) N) N
LEFT JOIN shots as rs
    ON rsc_rs_id = 345354
    AND DATE_FORMAT(N.PivotDate,'%Y%m')=DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(rs.timestamp),'%Y%m')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(N.PivotDate,'%Y%m')
```

Comment: i give it a try, but this seems not to work?

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(N.PivotDate,'%Y%m')
FROM (
   select ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL N MONTH) PivotDate
   FROM (
       select 0 N union all
       select 1 union all
       select 2 union all
       select 3 union all
       select 4 union all
       select 5 union all
       select 6) N) N` this one throws out the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL N MONTH) PivotDate
   FROM (
       select 0 N' at line 3`

Comment: @Michael I tried that part alone, and it gave me 7 rows. Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi i have version 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.8-log

Comment: @Michael everything in there should work with 5.0.. but try replacing `ADDDATE` with `DATE_ADD`.

Comment: @Richard oh okay, now it works! Strange thing, there were some invisible charackters when i copy the code from here... i converted the code into pure text bevore using it.

Comment: also perfect, i marked it! i guess this one is the more smarter... ;)

Answer (score 1):

In such cases it's common to use a table of `dates` with all dates (e.g. from 1/1/1970 to 31/12/2999) and `LEFT JOIN` your data to that table.

See an example in the answer here: [mysql joins tables creating missing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716016/mysql-joins-tables-creating-missing-dates)

If you create a dates table you can use:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(d.date,'%Y%m') AS `month`, count(rs.rsc_id) AS `counter`
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN shots as rs
   ON d.date = FROM_UNIXTIME(rs.timestamp)
   AND rs.rsc_rs_id = 345354
WHERE d.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH)
AND d.date < CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(d.date,'%Y%m');
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but unix timestamp [cannot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) hold dates beyond 19-Jan-2038. So, the list of months could be slightly reduced. :)

Comment: @Andriy Correct, that's why I usually don't use unix timestamp, I like to plan ahead :) The dates in my table are TIMESTAMP, I will edit accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: of course, left join... but this solution seems not to be good with speed. instead i used a subselect statement with union like `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH),'%Y%m') datum
UNION
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH),'%Y%m') datum UNION ...`